# Running SSHD on multiple ports on CentOS release 6.2 (Final)

Tags: centos, ssh, redhat, centos6.2

I am running CentOS release 6.2 (Final).

I want the sshd port of listen on ports 22 and 1022.

I have add the following lines to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Port 22
Port 1022
```

and restarted sshd and turned iptables off however I cannot connect to sshd on port 1022.

Even if I do the following

```
#Port 22
Port 1022
```

sshd continues listening on port 22 and does not listen on port 1022. I have tried other port values besides 1022 but no luck.

Help!

Comment: Choose a different alternative port than 1022. People like to use port 2222, for instance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you were using CentOS 5 the configuration you describe does work but a quick test suggests that sshd on CentOS 6 won't bind to any port below 1023 except 22 - I can't find a reference for this at the moment. If you want to access sshd on multiple ports then pick one >=1024.

---

Update - this is related to SELinux. Current policy doesn't allow sshd to bind to non standard ports below 1023 (as experiment confirms) e.g.

```
semanage port -l | grep 22
ssh_port_t                     tcp      22
```

If you want to add an additional port <=1023 you will have to explicitly allow it in SELinux

```
semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t  -p tcp 1022
semanage port -l | grep 22
ssh_port_t                     tcp      1022, 22
```

then restart sshd

```
netstat -tnlp
tcp      0    0 0.0.0.0:22          0.0.0.0:*             LISTEN      25376/sshd
tcp      0    0 0.0.0.0:1022        0.0.0.0:*             LISTEN      25376/sshd
```

Comment: oh wow ... amazing

Comment: This appears necessary even for ports >=1024.

Comment: Yes, it's an SELinux issue. You can only bind to ports that are of type  `ssh_port_t`.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically not recommended but anyway this is achieve-able.

```
cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config-another
```

Edit the `sshd-config-another` file and assign different port no and pid file.

```
Port 1022
PidFile /var/run/sshd-another.pid
```

Now run,

```
ln -s /usr/sbin/sshd /usr/bin/sshd-another
cp /etc/rc.d/init.d/sshd /etc/rc.d/init.d/sshd-another
```

Open the new init script and make changes accordingly.

```
# config: /etc/ssh/sshd_config-another
# pidfile: /var/run/sshd-another.pid
[ -f /etc/sysconfig/sshd-another ] && . /etc/sysconfig/sshd-another
prog="sshd-another"
SSHD=/usr/sbin/sshd-another
PID_FILE=/var/run/sshd-another.pid
```

Create `/etc/sysconfig/sshd-second` file.

```
OPTIONS="-f /etc/ssh/sshd_config-another"
```

Separate PAM configuration.

```
ln -s /etc/pam.d/sshd /etc/pam.d/sshd-another
```

Restart the service.

```
service sshd restart
service sshd-another restart
```

Chkconfig it.

```
chkconfig --add sshd-another
chkconfig on sshd-another
```

Comment: Hi Iain, can you point me to the documentation please. I must have been overlooking things then.

Comment: Look up the Port directive in man sshd_config.

Comment: This answer is interesting but is an answer to a different question, which would be: can I run two different `sshd` instances with two different configs? And you're writing how to do it. This is useful in particular when some server has to ensure continuity of a ssh service which was served by another machine with another private server key.

Answer (score 0):

With demise of Centos, I thought it might be helpful to link the
solutions in Red Hat Customer portal to configure multiple SSHD
services on different ports (i.e., have a different port for third
party vendors to connect non-standard port).

Please note: The RHEL links only showed changing the port, but not
all the other SSH hardening techniques used

From this CENTOS article above, it was smart to change the "PidFile"
PidFile /var/run/sshd-another.pid

RHEL LINKS:

LINK : https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1166283  2nd SSHD on RHEL7/8
LINK : https://access.redhat.com/solutions/63129    2nd SSHD on RHEL5/6

SSH HARDENING TIPS:

LINK : dev-sec.io/baselines/ssh

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/508197)